# How to remove lines beginning with a specific character

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm stuck with the situation where I have to remove all lines from code where lines are beginning with #include, like so:

```
#include 'utils/namespace.js'
#include 'utils/constants.js'
#include 'utils/helpers.js'
#include 'utils/json2.js'
#include 'utils/polifill.js'
```

Any suggestions? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you restricted to use gulp for this?

Comment: Wouldn't any editor with search and replace do the job?

Comment: Use [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace). The regex is `/^#include.*/g`, the replacement is `''` (empty string).

Comment: gernberg, yes, i've just started using it in a project, so changing it won't be a good idea.  isherwood, I don't to do it manually every time I want to build a project so that's not a case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it will work, but how about something like this?

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src(['file.txt'])
    .pipe(replace(/#include[^\n]*/g, ''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/file.txt'));
});
```

Comment: `/^\s*#\s*include.*[\r\n]+/gm` might be more thorough (if the replace is run on the entire file, not line-by-line). Also allows whitespace either side of the `#` (in case these are C files).

Comment: Thanks guys, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `gulp-replace` is a good use case for this, as Ipg's answer demonstrates.

But here's a slightly more "low-level" way of doing it using [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var through = require("through2");

gulp.task("templates", function() {
  return gulp
    .src("src/file.txt")
    .pipe(through.obj(function(file, enc, done) {
      var replaced = file.contents.toString().replace(/#include[^\n]*/g, "");
      file.contents = new Buffer(replaced);
      done(null, file);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```